# javascript addeventlistener with prototype

Tags: javascript, bind

I have a simple html5 canvas element I am adding event listeners to via an object.

```
function myObj(cv, ctx) {
    this.canvas = cv;
    this.context = ctx
    this.Init();
}
myObj.prototype.DownEvent = function(e) {
    //do stuff here
}
myObj.prototype.Init = function () {
  this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",this.DownEvent,false); // DOES NOT WORK
  this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.DownEvent.bind(this), false); //this works.
}
```

My question is why does the line tagged "DOES NOT WORK" not properly work? Why do I have to use .bind() in order for the event listener to work?

Comment: See the linked question. E.g., `this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",this.DownEvent.bind(this),false);` Also: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) (on my anemic little blog).

Comment: Thanks for the info :)